# Where is the "SDK Development Console" in Google app engine's eclipse plugin?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using trying google app engine in eclipse with the google app engine plugin.

In the section "Understanding Write Costs" of https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities, I read

> You can see how many writes will be required to store an entity by looking at the data viewer in the SDK Development Console

However, I can't find this view in eclipse, so I think I'm missing something here.

**Q: Where is the "SDK Development Console" ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check it here: [Development Console](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#The_Development_Console)

Once you are there you can see the column ***Write Ops*** which will tell you the write ops needed to store that entity.